# ConfigModule.withConfig or provideConfig in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

What is the difference between those two configs and which should be used when?

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({})
```

and

```
provideConfig({})
```

The documentation didn't provide the clear answer to this question.
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/global-configuration-in-spartacus/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs, they are the same.

ConfigModule.withConfig({}) behaves the same way as provideConfig({})

The difference between them is that the first is used to be used in import's array, whereas the latter is used in the provider's array

However, you can create an issue in the Spartacus repository https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues in order to open the discussion of deprecating `ConfigModule.withConfig`

'legacy' way

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ConfigModule.withConfig({...})],
  providers: [...]
  ...
})
...
```

'preferred' way

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [provideConfig({...})]
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Full examples:

old:

```js
import {CmsConfig, ConfigModule} from "@spartacus/core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents:{
        YourCustomComponentFlexType: {
          component: YourCustomComponent
        }
      }
    } as CmsConfig),
  ],
})
```

or
**preferred one:**

```js
import {provideConfig} from "@spartacus/core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        YourCustomComponentFlexType: {
          component: YourCustomComponent
        }
      }
    }),
  ]
})
```